# MySQL - Getting tags concatenated in a hierarchical way

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, temp-tables, hierarchical-trees

I've got a temporary (this is important, as I cannot open it twice on the same query to make `JOIN`) table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_report_tags` (
 `report_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `report_title` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `attr_value_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `attr_category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `attribute_count` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

With some sample data:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| report_id | report_title | attr_value_id | attr_category_id | attribute_count |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | SEN vs PUR   |            16 |                2 |               3 |
|         1 | SEN vs PUR   |            34 |                3 |              43 |
|         2 | PRA vs TLS   |            35 |                1 |              48 |
|         2 | PRA vs TLS   |            36 |                2 |              51 |
|         2 | PRA vs TLS   |            37 |                2 |               4 |
|         2 | PRA vs TLS   |            51 |                3 |               5 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

### What I need

I need to get the `value_id` concatenated according to categories, only if the report has all of the needed categories the user wants.

So, in the given example, if the user says *"I want to see reports by `category_id` 1, 2 and 3"*, I'd need to show the following:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+
| value_tree | report_id | report_title |
+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 35,36,51   |         2 | PRA vs TLS   |
| 35,37,51   |         2 | PRA vs TLS   |
+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

As you can see, as report with ID 1 does not have category 1 it must be hidden from the result set, and as report with ID 2 has two values for category 2, it has to show two results, one with each tree of combinations.

If it had three values for `category_id = 3`, then I should get all the tree possible combinations for it.

**I'm using PHP too, so a solution with parsing data and working with it can be also a correct one.**

I've been trying to work with `GROUP_CONCAT()`, `HAVING COUNT(category_id)` and `ORDER BY FIELD(category_id)`, but I haven't been able to make it to appear a result for every possible combination, as I cannot use JOINs.

Thanks everyone for your help and your time!

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think this is possible via SQL only because (1) You say you can't JOIN and (2) I know of no other way to have 1 row in the source row (in your case value = 35) become more than 1 row (in your case 2 rows) in the result set. You may be better off creating a new question, focused solely on the PHP/ reformatting aspect of the problem.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but stackoverflow has shown me so many times that when I think there's no possible solution then someone thinks of a better way. I will wait a little before doing so, but I think I will follow your advice. Thank you for your time and your comment!

Comment: To me the problem is your use of CSV, and the fact that you are using a temporary table (versus a permanent one with sessions and a cleanup)